# How to decouple an event-driven module?

Tags: java, decoupling, event-driven, jsfml

A little background may be needed, but skip to **Problem** if you feel confident. Hopefully the summary gets the point across.

## Summary

I have an `InputDispatcher` which dispatches events (mouse, keyboard, etc...) to a `Game` object.

I want to scale `InputDispatcher` independently of `Game`: `InputDispatcher` should be able to support more events types, but `Game` should not be forced to use all of them.

## Background

This project uses JSFML.

Input events are handled through the `Window` class via `pollEvents() : List<Event>`. You must do the dispatching yourself.

I created a `GameInputDispatcher` class to decouple event handling from things such as handling the window's frame.

```
Game game = ...;
GameInputDispatcher inputDispatcher = new GameInputDispatcher(game);

GameWindow window = new GameWindow(game);

//loop....
inputDispatcher.dispatch(window::pollEvents, window::close);
game.update();
window.render();
```

<sup>The loop has been simplified for this example</sup>

```
class GameInputDispatcher {
    private Game game;

    public GameInputDispatcher(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void dispatch(List<Event> events, Runnable onClose) {
        events.forEach(event -> {
            switch(event.type) {
                case CLOSE: //Event.Type.CLOSE
                    onClose.run();
                    break;
                default:
                    // !! where I want to dispatch events to Game !!
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## The Problem

In the code directly above (`GameInputDispatcher`), I could dispatch events to `Game` by creating `Game#onEvent(Event)` and calling `game.onEvent(event)` in the default case.

But that would force `Game` to write the implementation for sorting & dispatching mouse and keyboard events:

```
class DemoGame implements Game {
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        // what kind of event?
    }
}
```

## Question

If I wanted to feed events from `InputDispacher` into `Game`, how could I do so while avoiding Interface Segregation Principle violations? <sup>(by declaring all listening methods: `onKeyPressed,`onMouseMoved`, etc.. inside of`Game`, even though they may not be used).</sup>

`Game` should be able to choose the form of input it wants to use. The supported input types (such as mouse, key, joystick, ...) should be scaled through `InputDispatcher`, but `Game` should not be forced to support all these inputs.

## My Attempt

I created:

```
interface InputListener {
    void registerUsing(ListenerRegistrar registrar);
}
```

`Game` would extend this interface, allowing `InputDispatcher` to depend on `InputListener` and call the `registerUsing` method:

```
interface Game extends InputListener { }

class InputDispatcher {
    private MouseListener mouseListener;
    private KeyListener keyListener;

    public InputDispatcher(InputListener listener) {
        ListenerRegistrar registrar = new ListenerRegistrar();
        listener.registerUsing(registrar);

        mouseListener = registrar.getMouseListener();
        keyListener = registrar.getKeyListener();
    }

    public void dispatch(List<Event> events, Runnable onClose) {
        events.forEach(event -> {
            switch(event.type) {
                case CLOSE:
                    onClose.run();
                    break;
                case KEY_PRESSED:
                     keyListener.onKeyPressed(event.asKeyEvent().key);
                     break;
                 //...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`Game` subtypes can now implement whatever listener is supported, then register itself:

```
class DemoGame implements Game, MouseListener {
   public void onKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key key) {

   }

    public void registerUsing(ListenerRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.registerKeyListener(this);
        //...
    }
}
```

## Attempt Issues

Although this allows `Game` subtypes to only implement the behaviors they want, **it forces any `Game` to declare `registerUsing`, even if they don't implement any listeners.**

This could be fixed by making `registerUsing` a `default` method, having all listeners extend `InputListener` to redeclare the method:

```
interface InputListener {
    default void registerUsing(ListenerRegistrar registrar) { }
}

interface MouseListener extends InputListener {
    void registerUsing(ListenerRegistrar registrar);

    //...listening methods
}
```

But this would be quite tedious to do for every listener I choose to create, violating DRY.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any point in `registerUsing(ListenerRegistrar)`.  If code external to the listener must be written which knows that this is a listener and therefore it needs to register with a `ListenerRegistrar`, then it may as well go ahead and register the listener with the registrar.

The Problem as stated in your question is usually handled in GUIs is by means of *default processing*, using either inheritance or delegation.

With inheritance, you would have a base class, call it `DefaultEventListener` or `BaseEventListener`, whatever you prefer, which has a `public void onEvent(Event event)` method that contains a switch statement which checks the type of event and invokes an overridable on itself for every event that it knows about.  These overridables generally do nothing.  Then your "game" derives from this `DefaultEventListener` and provides overriding implementations only for the events that it cares about.

With delegation you have a `switch` statement in which you check for the events that you know about, and in the `default` clause of your `switch` you delegate to some `defaultEventListener` of type `DefaultEventListener` which probably does nothing.

There is a variation which combines both: event listeners return `true` if they process the event, in which case the `switch` statement immediately returns so that the event will not be processed any further, or `false` if they do not process the event, in which case the `switch` statement `break`s, so code at the end of the `switch` statement takes control, and what it does is to forward the event to some other listener.

An alternative approach (used in many cases in SWT for example) involves registering an observer method for each individual event that you can observe.  If you do this then be sure to remember to deregister every event when your game object dies, or else it will become a zombie.  Applications written for SWT are full of memory leaks caused by gui controls that are never garbage-collected because they have some observer registered somewhere, even though they are long closed and forgotten.  This is also a source of bugs, because such zombie controls keep receiving events (for example, keyboard events) and keep trying to do things in response, even though they have no gui anymore.

Comment: `registerUsing` was a way to avoid `Game` knowing about it's containers (which `InputDispatcher` is one of them). `InputListenerRegistrar` decouples the registering from `InputDispatcher`. This allows me to remove replace the `InputDispatcher` with whatever I'd like, encouraging reusability.

Comment: As for `DefaultEventListener`, I do not want to perform any more type checking than I already do (which I only do cause JSFML basically forces it). Using that technique still violates ISP, as methods that aren't used will still be declared. Even though `DemoGame` doesn't have to declare it, it's still in `DemoGame`'s interface. "Do nothing" methods themselves are code smells. I could have kept `registerUsing` default and not redeclare it in `KeyListener` and `MouseListener` if I wanted that kind of behavior.

Comment: That's how several existing guis do it.  (Win32, MFC, WinForms, Swing, SWT, a gui that I have built myself in its entirety, etc.)  So, like it or not, smelly or not, that's how a lot of people who have a lot of experience on these matters have decided to do it. And you know how everyone thinks they know better and they will do it differently? Well, in this case, they generally don't do it differently.  There must be a reason for it.  Do what you will with this information.

Comment: "*Then your `Game` derives from this DefaultEventListener and provides overriding implementations only for the events that it cares about.*" - Not a single GUI toolkit does this/encourages this. I don't mean to sound jumpy, but it's bad design, flooding the type's interface (which is a huge no-no). Next thing you know [I'm throwing `UnsupportedOperationExceptions`](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337850/is-expecting-the-api-user-to-implement-an-unsupportedoperationexception-okay). Mind giving me an example of where you've seen this?

Comment: Look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx  See all the overridable methods that begin with "On...()"?  They do nothing.  You override them if you need to do something.

Comment: Look how massively large that interface is. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Could you give me a non-C++ example? Considering my question is about Java, the two languages have two different sets of devs, and it's no secret that Java devs tend to be a bit nearer about how they write code. And I really hate sounding bias like that, don't get me wrong, but the verbosity of C++ tends to have an affect on design mentality.

Comment: That's not just C++, that's dotNet, so on the page you saw there is a tab that you can use to select C#, C++, F#, VB.  Specifically C# is very much like java.  There is no point in trying to avoid a massive interface, because only one base framework class needs to be so large.  I repeat: you override only what you want to use.

Comment: What I'm saying is I can achieve the same behavior you are suggesting by making `registerUsing` a `default` method. Doing so would only expose 1 "do nothing" method as opposed to a scalable amount of "do nothing" methods (what if I wanted to support a new peripheral, such as VR? That would require a few more methods, which may not be used). That 1 "do nothing" is still a code smell, which suggests there's a deeper design issue, which I'm trying to pinpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134866/discussion-between-vince-emigh-and-mike-nakis).

Answer (score 0):

While reiterating the issue to a friend, I believe I found the issue.

> Although this allows Game subtypes to only implement the behaviors they want, it forces any Game to declare registerUsing, even if they don't implement any listeners.

This suggests `Game` is already violating ISP: if clients won't use listeners, `Game` should not derive from `InputListener`.

If, for some reason, a `Game` subtype did not want to use listeners (maybe interaction is handled via Web pages or the local machine), `Game` should not be forced to declare `registerUsing`.

## Solution

Instead, an `InteractiveGame` could derive from `Game` and implement `InputListener`:

```
interface Game { }
interface InteractiveGame extends Game, InputListener { }
```

The framework would then have to check the type of `Game` to see if it needs to instantiate an `InputDispatcher`:

```
Game game = ...;
if(game instanceof InteractiveGame) {
    // instantiate input module
}
```

If someone can suggest a better design, please do so. This design was an attempt to decouple event dispatching from programs that want to make use of user events, while enforcing strong compile-time-safety.